# How do I assign a Vue object's properties, one by one, from a bunch of computed values?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a bunch of Vue objects from some jumbled JSON. I can create a clean array for each type of properties, but I don't know how to take these arrays and map them to the Vue objects.

Trying to stick to ES6. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rachidmrad/rfuLxgpz/1/

HTML

```html
<div class="card w-50" v-for="brewery in breweries">
 <div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Brewery: {{ brewery.name }}</h5>
   <p class="card-text">
    Location: {{ brewery.location }}<br />
    Specialities: {{ brewery.speciality }}<br />
    Tier: {{ brewery.tier }}
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
data() {
  return {
    breweries:
      {
        name: [],
        location: [],
        speciality: [],
        tier: []
      }
  }
},

mounted() {
  let thisBrewery = this.name,
      thisLocation = this.location,
      thisSpeciality = this.speciality,
      thisTier = this.tier;

// Get values from JSON - pretty sure I go this part right
  get('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1CTlh5HuhQd44_bTuQF_X02QzJpa0ReQJB5jb8MSFvO8/od6/public/values?alt=json')
    .then((data) => {
      let json = JSON.parse(data);
      maxEntry = json.feed.entry.length /4 - 1;
      for (let i = 0; i < maxEntry; i++) {
          thisBrewery[i] = json.feed.entry[j].content.$t;
          thisLocation[i] = json.feed.entry[j + 1].content.$t;
          thisSpeciality[i] = json.feed.entry[j + 2].content.$t;
          thisTier[i] = json.feed.entry[j + 3].content.$t;
          j = j + 4;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('oops');
  });
}
```

I basically need to map thisBrewery to breweries.name, thisLocation to breweries.location, etc.

I don't believe the JSON is relevant here (I tested the arrays I'm calculating in a non-Vue app and they check out) but feel free to beautify and look at the data: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1CTlh5HuhQd44_bTuQF_X02QzJpa0ReQJB5jb8MSFvO8/od6/public/values?alt=json (this is a Google Sheet JSON)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML suggests you are expecting an array of `brewery` objects with each object containing `name`, `location` properties etc. But, you have one `breweries` object with an array for each values in your data. So, create an array of brewery objects and `push` it to `breweries`.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      breweries: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1CTlh5HuhQd44_bTuQF_X02QzJpa0ReQJB5jb8MSFvO8/od6/public/values?alt=json')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(json => {
        for (let j = 4; j < json.feed.entry.length; j += 4) {
          const name = json.feed.entry[j].content.$t,
            location = json.feed.entry[j + 1].content.$t,
            speciality = json.feed.entry[j + 2].content.$t,
            tier = json.feed.entry[j + 3].content.$t;

          // push an object to the array
          this.breweries.push({ name, location, speciality, tier });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('oops');
      });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card w-50" v-for="brewery in breweries">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Brewery: {{ brewery.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          Location: {{ brewery.location }}<br /> Specialities: {{ brewery.speciality }}<br /> Tier: {{ brewery.tier }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note:

- With your old structure, you could've done `v-for="(name, index) in breweries.name"` and use the `index` to get other properties like `{{ breweries.location[index] }}`
- `let thisBrewery = this.name` should've been `this.breweries.name`
- You can skip the `get` function and use the native [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead
- You can directly use `j` in the `for` loop and increment it with `4`
- [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you so much! I especially appreciate the extra notes.